# npm install got different versions according to node-semver

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, semantic-versioning

I found a case that npm dependency selection didn't follow node-semver.
I was trying to install `superagent@1.8.5`, and here is the dependency tree I got from `npm ls`:

```
└─┬ superagent@1.8.5
  ├── component-emitter@1.2.1
  ├── cookiejar@2.0.6
  ├─┬ debug@2.6.9
  │ └── ms@2.0.0
  ├── extend@3.0.0
  ├─┬ form-data@1.0.0-rc3
  │ ├── async@1.5.2
  │ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.8
  │ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0
  │ └─┬ mime-types@2.1.26
  │   └── mime-db@1.43.0
  ├── formidable@1.0.16
  ├── methods@1.1.2
  ├── mime@1.3.4
  ├── qs@2.3.3
  ├─┬ readable-stream@1.0.27-1
  │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
  │ ├── inherits@2.0.4
  │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
  │ └── string_decoder@0.10.31
  └── reduce-component@1.0.1
```

And here I got `formidable@1.0.16`
But when I looked into the `dependencies` of [superagent@1.8.5](http://registry.npmjs.org/superagent/1.8.5), we can get:

```
dependencies: {
    qs: "2.3.3",
    formidable: "~1.0.14",
    mime: "1.3.4",
    component-emitter: "~1.2.0",
    methods: "~1.1.1",
    cookiejar: "2.0.6",
    debug: "2",
    reduce-component: "1.0.1",
    extend: "3.0.0",
    form-data: "1.0.0-rc3",
    readable-stream: "1.0.27-1"
},
```

The dependency range for `formidable` is `~1.0.14`, which means it will take the latest patch version of `1.0.X`, since there is no dependency conflict on `formidable`.

However, the latest `1.0.X` of `formidable` is `1.0.17` [ref link](https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable), and when I tried the [official semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/), I can also get that the satisfied versions are `1.0.14, 1.0.15, 1.0.16, 1.0.17`.

I wanna ask is there any other rules for dependency resolution that I have missed?
Thanks!

Comment: as for `fomidable` the latest `1.0.X` is actually 1.0.16 according to [its npm document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) (versions tab), there actually is no 1.0.17 version.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply!  But on that page, you can select `show deprecated versions`, then you can see the `1.0.17`, I think maybe `deprecated` is the reason why `1.0.17` is not installed. Will try to find some other case to check this.

Comment: yeah must be that. you're welcome. :)